# Identical C Code Behaves Differently

Tags: c

I declared an empty string:

```
char str[MAX_LEN] = "\0"; //empty String
```

and then

```
void InitString(char *str,int maxlenght)
{

    char input = 0;
    int counter = 0,i;
    for(i = 0;i<(maxlenght);i++)
    {
        *(str+i) = '\0';
    }
    getchar();
    printf("\nEnter new string of max %d chars:  ",maxlenght);
    while (input != '\r' && counter < (maxlenght-1))
     {
        input = getche();
        *(str+counter) = input;
        counter++;
    }
}

void PrintString(char *str)
{

    int i = 0;
    printf("\nThe String Created is :  ");
    puts(str);
    while(*(str+i) != '\0')
    {
          printf("%c", *(str+i));
        i++;
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this code behaves differently since the code is identical in logic to the upper one.

```
int  CountWords(char *str)
{


    int i = 0;
    char ch;
    while(*(str+i) != '\0')
    {
          printf("%d", *(str+i));
         ch = *(str+i);
         printf("%c",ch);
         numNumber++;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

There is no output for the lower code block even though the test condition is the same.

Comment: I personally recommend using str[i] != '\0' instead of *(str+i) != '\0' since in my opinion it is cleaner to read

Comment: when you have a question about some code that does not work, post code that is short, cleanly compiles, and still exhibits the problem.  Since this is a runtime problem, post the actual input, post the expected output post the actual output.

Comment: the function: `getche()` is non standard C, and why use it when you have `getchar()` available?  in general, be checking for '\n' for end of line (unless you have some 'special' communication that actually passes '\r'.  In the second code snippit what is the variable: `numNumber`? and what does it have to do with the problem?  Oh, BTW: just what is the problem?

Comment: Cant use [] except creating. Ill take notes for problametic posting , numNumber is unrelevent here. , using getche so look will stop after 100 (get char get until the end overdrafting non existing array.

Comment: + if you see on the method printstring i make reset for array by each pointer giving '\0' (full)  than getch replace again new chars in locating and '\0' is left till end so array and the while have the '\0' always. And still.. + the method prints the asiic if i use %d but wont print the %c.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using `puts()`. [This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_puts.htm) states

> The C library function int puts(const char *str) writes a string to stdout up to but not including the null character. A newline character is appended to the output.

Thus, if `puts()` uses `strlen()` then your `'\0'` is replaced by a `'\n'` and that is why your while loop doesn't work.

Comment: Puts(str) there works perfect the countnumner method area wint work.